# What is the front camera resolution for recording video on a Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge?

Tags: front-camera, samsung-galaxy-s-6

Most resources I've found seem to say 1080p, but I found a Youtube demo that goes up to 1440p. Which is right?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this forum post](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-note-4/453075-does-front-facing-camera-record-video-2k-4k-all.html#post3994593), which shows the below image, the S6 is certainly capable of 1440p video. It seems that it's not the default setting. It's unclear why so many review sites that I found have misquoted the resolution.

[image]